# Install Corda Demobench in Ubuntu

Tags: installation, corda

Are there any instructions on how to install the Corda Demobench on Ubuntu? 
There is a download section [here](https://www.corda.net/downloads/) which offers installers for Windows and Mac OS X. 
 There is a link for how to build a [linux installer](https://docs.corda.net/demobench.html) but I can't find any links to the source code.

Comment: Can you update the question with a description of the missing information?

Comment: OK, I refined the 'missing information' bit.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I see the problem. I'll update the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scripts referred to in the documentation can be found here: https://github.com/corda/corda/tree/master/tools/demobench.

To build the installer, clone the Corda repository (`git clone https://github.com/corda/corda`) and run the script.

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Clone the Corda from git:

```
https://github.com/corda/corda.git
```

Navigate to demobench:

```
cd #directory you cloned#/corda/tools/demobench
```

Run:

```
./gradlew tools:demobench:installDist
```

This will build demobench.

Lastly you can navigate to the build directory:

```
cd tools/demobench/build/install/demobench
```

and run the tool:

```
bin/demobench
```